# How to send a key press after capturing another key event in X11

Tags: python, input, keyboard, x11, xlib

I'm trying to implement a Python script in Linux to capture the key press `a` send the key press `a` again (so it sends `a` twice).

Through some code at https://github.com/PeterHo/Linalfred/blob/master/src/globalhotkey.py I arrived at the following.

The key is captured fine, but sending the key press event does nothing. What am I missing here?

I also looked at the question [globally capture, ignore and send keyevents with python xlib, recognize fake input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038979/globally-capture-ignore-and-send-keyevents-with-python-xlib-recognize-fake-inp). The posted solution doesn't even appear to receive the events (after porting the `print` to Python 3).

```
import time

from Xlib import X, protocol
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.ext import record

display = None
root = None

def handler(reply):
    data = reply.data
    while len(data):
        event, data = protocol.rq.EventField(None).parse_binary_value(data, display.display, None, None)
        if event.type == X.KeyPress:
            keycode = event.detail
            print(keycode)
            if keycode == 38:
                window = Display().get_input_focus().focus
                event = protocol.event.KeyPress(
                    time=int(time.time()),
                    root=root,
                    window=window,
                    same_screen=0, child=X.NONE,
                    root_x=0, root_y=0, event_x=0, event_y=0,
                    state=0,
                    detail=keycode
                )
                window.send_event(event, propagate=True)
                event = protocol.event.KeyRelease(
                    time=int(time.time()),
                    root=root,
                    window=window,
                    same_screen=0, child=X.NONE,
                    root_x=0, root_y=0, event_x=0, event_y=0,
                    state=0,
                    detail=keycode
                )
                window.send_event(event, propagate=True)


def main():
    global display, root
    display = Display()
    root = display.screen().root

    ctx = display.record_create_context(
        0,
        [record.AllClients],
        [{
            'core_requests': (0, 0),
            'core_replies': (0, 0),
            'ext_requests': (0, 0, 0, 0),
            'ext_replies': (0, 0, 0, 0),
            'delivered_events': (0, 0),
            'device_events': (X.KeyReleaseMask, X.ButtonReleaseMask),
            'errors': (0, 0),
            'client_started': False,
            'client_died': False,
        }]
    )
    display.record_enable_context(ctx, handler)
    display.record_free_context(ctx)

    while True:
        # Infinite wait, doesn't do anything as no events are grabbed.
        event = root.display.next_event()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled quite a bit more today, and came across [Sending key presses to specific windows in X](http://paulsrandomcontent.blogspot.com/2013/10/for-project-i-wanted-to-send-key.html), which worked for me.

The key idea is to use `display` instead of `window` to send the events, and to `sync` the display. Without syncing the display, the key press won't be registered at all.

```py
disp.send_event(window, event, propagate=True)
disp.sync()
```

Applied that to our script above, we have the following working version:

```
import time

from Xlib import X, protocol
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.ext import record

display = None
root = None

def handler(reply):
    data = reply.data
    while len(data):
        event, data = protocol.rq.EventField(None).parse_binary_value(data, display.display, None, None)
        if event.type == X.KeyPress:
            keycode = event.detail
            print(keycode)
            if keycode == 38:
                disp = Display()
                window = disp.get_input_focus().focus
                root = disp.screen().root
                event = protocol.event.KeyPress(
                    time=0,
                    root=root, window=window, same_screen=0, child=X.NONE,
                    root_x=0, root_y=0, event_x=0, event_y=0,
                    state=0, detail=keycode
                )
                disp.send_event(window, event, propagate=True)
                disp.sync()
                event = protocol.event.KeyRelease(
                    time=0,
                    root=root, window=window, same_screen=0, child=X.NONE,
                    root_x=0, root_y=0, event_x=0, event_y=0,
                    state=0, detail=keycode
                )
                disp.send_event(window, event, propagate=True)
                disp.sync()


def main():
    global display, root
    display = Display()
    root = display.screen().root

    ctx = display.record_create_context(
        0,
        [record.AllClients],
        [{
            'core_requests': (0, 0),
            'core_replies': (0, 0),
            'ext_requests': (0, 0, 0, 0),
            'ext_replies': (0, 0, 0, 0),
            'delivered_events': (0, 0),
            'device_events': (X.KeyReleaseMask, X.ButtonReleaseMask),
            'errors': (0, 0),
            'client_started': False,
            'client_died': False,
        }]
    )
    display.record_enable_context(ctx, handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You can improve the code in your answer by removing the unnecessary `while True:` loop. If you want to fix the window receiving the second `a` you can move the lines assigning `disp`, `window`, and `root` out of the handler function (don't forget to rename root to avoid conflicts). The question which remains open is: how to stop a keystroke from being propagated to the currently focused window, so that you can translate a keystroke to another keystroke and not only add an additional one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I removed `while True:`. Moving `disp` and `root` appears to break some things.

Comment: Test it yourself if you can confirm that the `display.record_enable_context(ctx, handler)` line is the last line executed in the Python script. The line `display.record_free_context(ctx)` and the line `event = root.display.next_event()` are never reached, so you can remove them like you have removed the loop.

Comment: By the way: `dir(display)` does not list the `display.record_enable_context()` and `display.record_create_context()` methods. How do you know about them and how to get other ones available, but not listed by dir(display)?

Comment: I suppose you need to call the `record_free_context()` in some kind of onExit() function to achieve a clean exit of the script. Or you can use the Python atexit module for this purpose.

Comment: I found them from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22368676.